# NVDA - custom input selected value on focus

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers, nvda

I have a simple input on my website like:

```
<label for="input">How many months?</label>
<input id="input" type="text">
```

Currently, after focus NVDA read: 
"How many months? 
selected 50" 
(50 is an example input value) 
 
Is it possible to NVDA read a custom selected value? Like: 
"How many months? 
selected 50 months"

For roles like slider there is aria-valuetext but I don't see any other helpful aria for input.

Comment: Why would you want it to read something different?  NVDA is telling the user what is currently selected by the text cursor.

Comment: I recommend against trying to override the default behavior of the assistive technology. That can only confuse users.

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Really, don't worry about it. I know that sounds trite but it is real advice based on years of working with screen reader users (and trying to do what you are trying to do).

Most screen reader users are already familiar with how field labels and values are spoken by their screen reader. By trying to override it you run the risk of confusing your users.

If you speak to a screen reader user you will likely find that this is true. It is so common an issue that it came up yet again a couple weeks ago on the WebAIM mailing list: http://webaim.org/discussion/mail_message?id=34398

Note this insightful comment from the thread:

> In fact, sometimes if you listen very carefully to a screen reader user talking, you can catch that we will pronounce words the same as our screen readers do--and we are not even aware of it.

You will have to use script, and any approach you take will be needlessly complicated (which is why I am not even trying to offer sample code).

I know I already left this as a comment on the question, but I thought making it a proper answer might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by using javascript to update the field after input to dynamically change the value "50" to "50 months".